# Check if there are only specified Django template variables in a string

Tags: python, django

I'm working on configurable email template and need to validate if only `available_variables` are used in the content. So if user put `{{ apple }}`, the form should return `ValidationError('This variable is unavailable')`.

**models.py:**

```
email_content = models.TextField()
```

**forms.py:**

```
def clean_email_content(self):
     email_content = self.cleaned_data['email_content']
     available_variables = ['{{ company_name }}', '{{ user_name }}']
     required_variables = ['{{ company_name }}']
     for required_variable in required_variables:
        if not required_variable in email_content:
                raise forms.ValidationError("{} is required".format(required_variable))
     # how to check if there are only `available_variables` in the content?
```

TL;DR

`email_content` cannot contain other variables (strings that starts with `{{` and ends with `}}`) than specified in `available_variables`

Should I use regex or can I validate this using some method from Django Template Engine?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the actual requirement?

Comment: use regex to grab all variables from `email_content` and then compare it with available variables.

Comment: do NOT use regexps. Django's template engine already have all the code needed to properly parse a template string into tokens, so just use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use the template engine's lexer instead (nb: django 1.11 code, might need to be adapted if you use django 2.x):

```
from django.template import base
lexer = base.Lexer("{{ var_one }} is one {% if var_two %}{{ var_two|upper }} is two {% endif %}")
tokens = lexer.tokenize()
for t in tokens:
    if t.token_type == base.TOKEN_VAR:
        print("{}: {}".format(t, t.contents)
```

I leave it up to you to read the template.base code to find out other useful features...

Also in your validation method you definitly want to catch ALL errors at once (instead of raising as soon as you found an error) so the user can fix all errors at once (unless you really want to drive your users mad, that is).

And finally, as Gasanov suggests in his answer, you also want to use sets to find both missing required vars and illegal ones - this is much more efficient than doing sequential lookups.

Comment: Oh, that's nice solution. But I'm getting `has no attribute 'TOKEN_VAR'` and instead used `base.TokenType.VAR` in django 2.2.

Comment: @Gasanov yes I'm still on django 1.11 ATM so code might need to be adapted for django 2.x (edited my answer accordingly, thx for pointing this).

Answer (score 1):

We can use regex to find all tags from `email_content`. After that we convert them to `set` and substract all `available_variables` from it to find all incorrect ones. If any exists - we throw `ValidationError`.

Note that `available_variables` is `set` itself and contains just tags, without curly brackets.
Our regex checks for any numbers of spaces between brackets and tag, so your users shouldn't be able to cheat.

```py
import re

def clean_email_content(self):
        email_content = self.cleaned_data['email_content']
        available_variables = {'company_name', 'user_name'}
        finds = re.findall(r"{{[ ]*(.*?)[ ]*}}", email_content)
        invalid_tags = set(finds) - available_variables
        if invalid_tags:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "Should not contain invalid tags: " + str(invalid_tags)
            )
        return email_content
```